# Is there a named scale for sets such as 75055 Imperial Star Destroyer or 75054 AT-AT

Tags: sets, star-wars, terminology, scale

I am looking for the name of the scale that most Star Wars sets use, that isn't minifigure scale as it has been scaled down to an appropriate size but still has an interior for minifigures, such as the Star Destroyer 75055 or the AT-AT 75054? Is there a specific name like there is for minifigure scale and Microscale?

Comment: Microscale is not well-defined to not include that, but LEGO also made some sets they called medium scale.

Comment: I've heard the term "ISD Scale" some times, refering to the first Imperial Star Destroyer. But I doubt that's official and it's not clear if other sets share the same scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can find, there are very few official "scale" terms used in LEGO. The term "Minifig-scale" is a fan term and is fairly loose, as the scale of the figs themselves don't really equate to reasonable human dimensions. Add to that the fact that minifig-scale vehicles and buildings have had variable relative sizes compared to minifigs, making it difficult to describe a standard scale that is officially used in LEGO sets.

There are a few "micro-scale" sets, including [Micro Scale Space Cruiser](https://brickset.com/sets/11910-1/Micro-Scale-Space-Cruiser), [Micro Scale](https://brickset.com/sets/20201-1/Micro-Scale), and [Micro Scale Bag End](https://brickset.com/sets/COMCON033-1/Micro-Scale-Bag-End). And, if you will forgive a bit of levity, there is the [Kitchen Scale](https://brickset.com/sets/852534-1/Kitchen-Scale-MF).

My favorite scale that LEGO officially produced was the [Midi-scale Millennium Falcon](https://brickset.com/sets/7778-1/Midi-scale-Millennium-Falcon)). However, they also did a [Midi-scale Star Destroyer](https://brickset.com/sets/8099-1/Midi-scale-Imperial-Star-Destroyer) that is totally NOT the same scale as the Falcon. So, even in their official terminology the "scale" is a rather fluid thing.

For a more indepth discussion of scale, they had one over on the [Brickset Forums](https://forum.brickset.com/discussion/21118/lego-scale). I particularly like MrShinyAndNew's answer (third one down as of this post).